# Hello graduation, goodbye moderator privileges?

Tags: support, graduation

So a full site has privileges associated with more reputation points needed:

- Users with 15 rep can flag posts.
- Users with 500 rep can review posts from new users.
- Users with 2,000 rep can edit any question or answer in the system.
- Users with 3,000 rep can cast close and open votes.
- Users with 10,000 rep can cast delete and undelete votes on questions, and have access to a moderation dashboard.
- Users with 15,000 rep can protect posts.
- Users with 20,000 rep can cast delete votes on negatively voted answers.

*Now we are still at Beta, users with 4000 rep have access to all the moderation tools.* **In fact, there are only two people at Bio with 20k rep.**

> What will happen with the poor souls like me with **4k < rep < 20k**? Will we loose
>   our moderator tools?

Comment: You'd think they would prorate these privileges so that sites with lower voting rates would still have a healthy pool of moderators.

Comment: Additionally there is a number of users around 8k reputation (including you) which are not too far away from the next level.

Comment: Ill have to agree with @canadianer on this one. Bio SE has a bit of a lower voting and acceptance rate, in the SE ecosystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will lose any privileges you now have if you don't meet the higher reputation requirements after graduation.

This is usually not a problem, as sites tend to have enough high reputation users to keep community moderation going. The only really important privilege is closing, and we have 41 users with 3k+ reputation that will still be able to close after graduation.

All the privileges with higher reputation barriers are nice to have, but they're not essential to community moderation. Deletion of posts is generally handled by diamond moderators on smaller sites anyway.

Comment: Thank you! How long do you think it will take for Bio to graduate? Will there be moderator pro temp elections and the likes to enhance moderation? What will happen to you? You are *the* moderator of Bio, right?

Comment: @AliceD The most recent graduated site took somewhere like 2-3 weeks after the design post to graduate. There will be elections for moderators a few weeks after graduation.

Comment: Holy smo$es, that is *fast*!

Answer (score 8):

Yes you will lose your privileges. You now have to regain them once more. This is also why SE waits a bit so there are enough regular users who do have enough rep to continue being a community moderator. Plus you are on the cusp of getting your 10k privileges back.

Comment: How can the site be moderated with n=2 20k+ users?

Comment: @alice slowly. It is unfortunate that there is a 16k user who isn't really active; otherwise, there would 3ish 20k users. Also, mod elections will take place and there will probably be 4-5 positions. So if those user have a rep less then 20k, it will be like we have 7 users except that mod votes are are instant.

Comment: That all makes sense. How much time you think will pass before we leave Beta?

Comment: @alice my guess would be whenever the site designers are pleased.

Comment: @dustin - it's usually 3 moderators unless the site is *very* active in which case it might be 4. Given the low numbers of high rep users I'd say they'd stick with 3 for the first year.

Comment: @ChrisF this site is way more active then health which has 4 mods though.

Comment: @dustin - fair enough. I hadn't double checked the stats when I posted that. However, Health is probably a special case - you probably need more moderation where the answers could possibly be harmful.