# Close privileges

Tags: support, closing

I have come back to this site after a long time and I have noticed that I cannot cast close votes or reopen votes anymore. I noticed that it now says that this privilege can only be achieved once I get 3000 reputation points. What has happened? When did this change? Is this related to the site graduating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After graduation 3k rep is needed by users to cast close and open votes. This used to be 500 rep before graduation.

See also [Hello graduation, goodbye moderator privileges?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/hello-graduation-goodbye-moderator-privileges)